# Is there a way to break excel vba password without using hex editor

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I forgot the password set for excel vba macro and i can not download hex Editor. 
Is there any other way to break the password?

Answer (score 0):

You can't fail with the Hook model example on this SO post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27508116/5757159